# Exchange Server: Is it possible to find out which user marked an email as read?

Tags: email, exchange, logging, exchange-2016

We are running a self hosted Exchange 2016 Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

There is a shared mailbox used by multiple users.
Users have been told to mark emails in this account only in special cases, such as when a corresponding order has been fulfilled etc.

Recently, many emails had been marked as read even though those emails should have stayed unread. No user claimed to have marked them as read.

Question: **Is there a way to find out which user marked those emails as unread? What about Logs?**

**UPDATE**:
I found that the AuditLogging for a defined mail account can be used to log actions in a mail account.
See directions here:

- [Mailbox audit logging in Exchange Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mailbox-audit-logging/mailbox-audit-logging?view=exchserver-2016)
- [Enable or disable mailbox audit logging for a mailbox in Exchange Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mailbox-audit-logging/enable-or-disable?view=exchserver-2016)

I have configured the audit logging as follows:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-Mailbox info@mydomain.com | fl *audit*

AuditEnabled     : True
AuditLogAgeLimit : 14.00:00:00
AuditAdmin       : {Update}
AuditDelegate    : {Update, Move}
AuditOwner       : {Move}
```

Then I moved a few mails around and marked an email as unread (using my personal outlook (as a delegate for this mail account)).
Entries from the log can be fetched by:

```
Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity info@mydomain.com -LogonTypes Owner,Delegate,Admin -StartDate (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) -ShowDetails -ResultSize 2000
```

Problem is that there are no log entries listet corresponding to my actions (move and read/unread).

**UPDATE 2:**

A MOVE-Action has been logged, but apparently a unread/read-Action does not get logged using my current audit log settings (the setting *UPDATE* seems not to log this).

Any ideas how to configure audit logging to capture the read/unread-Status-Change of an email?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms526163(v=exchg.10)

Comment: and how can i configure Exchange in order to log a change of read/unread?

Comment: If you rely on users not making mistakes you're in for a rough ride. Why not provide personal mail accounts and use e.g. a distribution list, or an *actual* order handling system?

Comment: i agree, but i am not able to change decisions made by management

Comment: Do the users use the actual account directly? Meaning do they log on to Exchange using the credentials of the shared account? If yes, this will not be possible since they are all the same user. If you do this via delegation it might be possible, but I don't know enough about Exchange to answer that.

Comment: - they access this mail account via delegation

Comment: This is not a good business process. You are re-purposing a function that designated an email as read for an internal process. Why not just change the process?

Comment: @vidarlo distribution lists are a terrible solution for scenarios like this, since no one receiving them has any visibility of what has/hasn't already been done / responded to.

Comment: I agree with Greg, read/unread isn't a good mechanism for reliably keeping track. There are too many scenarios where emails could be marked as Read without realising, for instance if the preview pane is enabled so the most recent email gets selected and marked when Outlook is opened. Perhaps something like completed orders get moved to another folder, that way everything (regardless of read state) in the Inbox is in progress / needing attention?

Comment: Outlook for all users is configured not to change an email read status when viewed. Users have to actively mark them as read. The mail account is indeed used by our  distribution department to receive orders. Mails stay in the main mail folder (unread) as long as they are not processed to keep track of them - it would be a problem with visibility to use their pesonal mail accounts. Alas, it is not my decision to make (management dictates the rules).

Comment: Is it even possible to track the change of the read/unread status?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it even possible to track the change of the read/unread status?

No, there's no native feature available in Exchange to track the change of read/unread status of a mail in the shared mailbox.

As regards to the mailbox audit logs you mentioned above, as illustrated in the following table, actions like marking an item as read/unread are not logged at all:
Reference: [Mailbox actions logged by mailbox audit logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mailbox-audit-logging/mailbox-audit-logging?view=exchserver-2016#mailbox-actions-logged-by-mailbox-audit-logging).
[image]

With the above being said, for your scenario, agree with the other replies that it's not a good idea to rely on the read/unread status in the work process. Personally, I'd recommend training the users to utilize other features like flagging or categorizing an item in Outlook.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-categories-flags-reminders-or-colors-a894348d-b308-4185-840f-aff63063d076

Comment: What about UPDATE? I mean, "An item's properties are updated" - is UNREAD/READ not a property? (well, obviously marking an email as "read" didn't trigger the logging)

Comment: @Thariama: doesn't make any difference, auditing wasn't enabled anyway. I doubt that auditing this particular action was ever discussed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of focusing on how to "catch" the person who marked an email as Read, why not focus on improving the process? You've said that you can't change the process, but surely you can improve it? Why not implement a step that when an email is read and the order is processed it gets moved to a subfolder named  "Processed" or "Completed"? What about creating a subfolder named "In Process" to move in process emails to? Add an additional step that the person who is working on a particular email/order sends an email to the rest of the group that they're working on order xxx? This way it can be assumed that every email in the Inbox is an unprocessed order, regardless of Read/Unread state? If it's in process or completed it's been moved to the appropriate subfolder. I can think of several ways to improve the process without needing to determine who marked an email as Read so that you can assign blame, or provide guidance to the "culprit", whichever the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange doesn't have a feature that directly logs or identifies which specific user marked an email as read.

A third party tool might be able to provide it, ManageEngine Exchange Reporter Plus for example.

Comment: But ManageEngine Exchange Reporter Plus can only use the features of Excahnge as i could - so if they can i should be able to do it too.

Comment: They might have done some custom development which interfaces API's like EWS. Im not a developer so can't help with that. Maybe someone on stackoverflow can help with that